# How to restore empty `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file?

Tags: files, restore

I was trying to fix plymouth using a script I found, the `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file is now empty!

So I don't know what this can means for my system. Can anyone help me restoring it?

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` is used to include modules in initramfs. This file has some lines which are commented out by default. That might means this file is effectively empty.

I am posting the default content of that file here. You may want to copy it and paste it in your files with a text editor and root privilege. To open the file with root power use `sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules` command.

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
```

If you add any modules name there, you need to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` command to update your currently used initramfs files.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: The file is same on default installation of Ubuntu and Edubuntu. So, I think the default one is exactly like I posted.

Comment: You could copy the file from `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/modules`