# How to load a module in initrd?

Tags: drivers, 15.04, initramfs, debugging, modprobe

I want to explicitly load a module (say, `netconsole`) during the initrd stage, similarly to `/etc/modules` in the main system startup procedure.

First, I checked that the initrd in my system already contains the wanted module (see Appendix).

I have looked into `/initrd.img` (which is a compressed cpio archive, so to have a quick look into it, I have done `zcat /initrd.img > initrd.cpio` and gone inside it with `mc`). I have looked for any invocations of `modprobe` among the scripts, and have figured out that the modules listed in `/conf/modules` (`/` is initrd's root here) get automatically loaded by the `load_modules()` function from `/scripts/functions` (called by `/init`).

But what would be the standard tool in the Ubuntu system to update `/conf/modules` of the initrd?

(BTW, during my study of the code of the Ubuntu's initrd, I noticed that there is some special support for `netconsole` in the `/init` script, which I might make work for my needs, but anyway ,my question is more general, concerning any other custom module.)

#### Appendix

As I said above: first, I checked that the initrd in my system already contains the wanted module (namely, `netconsole`). This is how:

```
# zcat /initrd.img | cpio --extract --verbose --list  | fgrep netconsole
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        25372 Aug 31 20:59 lib/modules/3.19.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/netconsole.ko
109504 blocks
#
```

And also I checked that it already contains the needed network driver:

```
# ls -ld /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 21 15:34 /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver -> ../../../../bus/pci/drivers/sky2
# zcat /initrd.img | cpio --extract --verbose --list  | fgrep sky2
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        92948 Aug 31 20:49 lib/modules/3.19.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/marvell/sky2.ko
109504 blocks
#
```

Comment: For future reference, `lsinitramfs` included in `initramfs-tools` does about the same as the `zcat /initrd.img ..` command illustrated here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I discovered how to add modules to the initrd in Ubuntu 14.04
I added the names of the modules to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules . This added the modules to the initrd file.  Do not forget to update the initrd file ( update-initramfs -u ) after you have made changes to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules .

Comment: How do you define module names ?  Now I need to add ahci.ko module? So what should be included in that file?

Comment: @sandundhammika `ahci`

Comment: How come my /etc/initramfs-tools/modules file is empty (just comment lines)? I'm using ubuntu 16.04. Hope someone could explain to me what's happened in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses initramfs-tools (see man initramfs-tools for an introduction) to handle the creation of initrd.

To add a module netconsole in initrd and force loading it create a file in /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks (i.e. /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/netconsole) with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
   echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
   prereqs
   exit 0
   ;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

force_load netconsole
```

and make it executable. Then run:

`update-initramfs -u`

to update the initrd of the newest kernel.

Comment: But isn't there a simpler way of just appending the module name to `/conf/modules`? Where should I put it in order for `update-initramfs -u` to use it?